# PM2 - How to access commands when other user installed pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have the following problem.

**User1** is admin and installed pm2 globally on a Windows 2008 R2 Server, and are able to run npm commands, start/stop servers, read logs, etc.

**User2** is also admin but can`t run the same commands on the same server of **User1**. I get this error below.

[image]

Things I already tried:

1. **User2** installing pm2 globally again on the same machine. But I have the same problem.
2. Cry!!

Comment: This is a `PATH` issue.

Comment: How do I add pm2 to path?

Comment: How do you add anything to your path? Same process.

Comment: I`ve already added nodejs and pm2 to the PATH, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Thanks @tadman PATH was pointing to:

"C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\bin"

and the correct path is

"C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Roaming\npm"